# Why does my lightbar draw more current when connected to a battery than a power supply

Tags: voltage, led, current

When I measure the current draw of the lights when connected to a car battery, they draw about 2.4A

[image]

However if I connect the lights to a 12V power supply, they only draw around 0.8A. Even though the power supply says it can output 5.4A at 12V
[image]

I'm just wondering why this is, and is it possible to force the power supply to give the lights 2.4A

Edit: after measuring the voltage of the power supply when the lights are connected, it is only 8V which explains why the current draw is lower. It does read 12V with nothing connected though, What does this mean?
Thanks

Comment: Measure the voltage as well. [Edit] your question to include the voltage readings.

Comment: 1) also measure **the voltage**. 2) the 5.4 A that the supply can deliver **may not be enough**. When **cold**, lightbulbs draw **significantly** more current compared to when they're **hot**. It only takes a **fraction of a second** for the light's filament to get hot. The battery will have no issue with that, the supply however will consider the high current an **overload** and will lower its output voltage. 3) the supply may be **faulty**.

Comment: @bimp assuming non-led light bar. Do they even sell those any more? OP tagged this led.

Comment: Have edited the post with voltage measurement